# Black Horizontal Scroll Bar Syntax Highlighter for Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, syntaxhighlighter

I have a blog using Syntax Highlighter plugin. I added the plugin in the header of the HTML theme.

This is the following plugin script :

```
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions START -->
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushAS3.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushBash.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushColdFusion.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushDelphi.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushDiff.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushErlang.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushGroovy.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJavaFX.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPerl.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPlain.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPowerShell.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushScala.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'/> 
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/> 

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions END -->
```

As seen above, I use the default theme (shThemeDefault.css) which has a bright color.
But when I put it on one of my blog post, why the horizontal scroll bar appears black? It's didn't matching with my bright blog theme. I do not mind the line scroll bar that appears, because it adjusts its size with the content on my blog. But the problem is the black color, which should have bright colors because I use the default theme.

This is the script that i use to highlight in my blog post :

```
<pre class="brush:xhtml">
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>
</pre>
```

And this is the appearance of a black horizontal scroll bar.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think i just found out that i have no problem with Syntax Highlighter plugin.
The black scroll bar color is appears because of my own custom blog theme. I try to find the keyword **"scroll"** on the theme of my blog, and I found it.

This is the source that i found in my blog theme :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
height:12px;
background: #474747;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: #000;
}
```

I just change the color above and the problem solved..